# Spring/Hibernate MySQL Driver settings for SSH connection

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I have been unable to find how to configure the MySql datasource settings to enable SSH connection to the database (instead of using the classic IP based connection) in my Spring/Hibernate persistence context.  Here is my persistenceContext.xml datasource bean definition:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
</bean>
```

And here is my persistence.properties file section where these properties are defined (this works with IP based connection only):

```
database.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.2:3306/db
database.user=root
database.password=password
```

I think there should be more properties available in order to setup the ssh connection such as `database.ssh.url` and `database.ssh.username` or something similar.  Do you know some way to do this?

Comment: have a look at http://www.razorsql.com/articles/mysql_ssl_jdbc.html

Comment: Thanks Ralph but that's using SSL not SSH.

Comment: I am looking to accomplish the same thing. If you find any thing please post here. Thank you.

Comment: looking for same thing

Answer (score 0):

In order to get access from your local app to your database server via ssh, the "only" extra thing you would need to do, is establish a previous SSH connection, before your DataSource object tries to get a connection.

A possible solution is detailed in this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35096140/4067559)