# Spring Boot Connection to MySQL on remote SSH server

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, jsch

I am trying to connect to MySQL server at remote machine using spring-boot application.properties but it is failing with error `o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup: Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource`.

My database URL is in the correct format. Remote Server requires `ssh` connection and I have connected it successfully using MySQL Workbench. For connection via spring-boot app, I checked solutions and implemented JSCH solution as explained in post:
[Spring Boot SSH Mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33526427/spring-boot-ssh-mysql/33593788) but still no success.

Remote Server SSH port is 202 instead of default 22. Any help on how to connect DB?

Answer (score -1):

Please refer information mention here - 
[here](https://techyhecky.blogspot.com/)

or 
[stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33526427/spring-boot-ssh-mysql)